# Java Exception: Unauthorized: 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, httphandler

I'm getting the error: `Exception: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401`, when trying to connect to Jira through HttpHeader, and the credentials are configured in a configserver file, which would be this:

```
@Component
public class JiraHttpHeadersHelper {

    @Value("${first.jira.auth.user}")
    private String firstJiraAuthUser;

    @Value("${first.jira.auth.psw}")
    private String firstJiraAuthPsw;


    public HttpHeaders jiraHeadersWithAuthentication() {
        String plainCreds = firstJiraAuthUser + ":" + firstJiraAuthPsw;

        System.out.println("Credenciales JiraServices: "+plainCreds);
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCreds.getBytes());
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic" + base64Creds);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        System.out.println("Authorization JiraServices: "+headers);
        return headers;
    }
}
```

And the method where I command to call the file above and where I get the error on the line `ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,this.requestEnt, String.class);`, would be this:

```
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPriorityJira() {

        //Request entity created
        this.requestEnt = new HttpEntity(this.jiraHttpHeadersHelper.jiraHeadersWithAuthentication());

        String jql = "priority";
        String url = jiraBaseURL + jql;
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,this.requestEnt, String.class);
            System.out.println("HttpStatus"+HttpStatus.OK);
            if (result.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                return result;
            } else {
                logger.error("Jira Generic User maybe blocked, status from API: " +result.getStatusCode() + ". Body: "+ result.getBody());
                return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getBody(), result.getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
            logger.error("Error getting priorityJira. Exception: "+ e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

In fact, when I run the debug and check the credentials, it brings them up without a problem. I've already searched, tried most of the links on this page and I can't find the solution.
Any help would be appreciated in this case, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your authorization header you concat your key with « Basic » without adding a white space.

```
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic" + base64Creds);
```

Instead of :

```
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
```

Maybe it’s just that.

Edit :
The answer was to add `StandardCharsets.UTF-8` to the String constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kizoku-Dev, with or without white space it keeps sending me the error:`Unauthorized: 401`

Comment: And with ```StandardCharsets.UTF-8``` as second parameters of string constructor ? Maybe a problem with your default encoding.